# Eclipse CVS ignore outgoing change but accept incoming change

Tags: eclipse, cvs

In my local environment, I have disabled some security code for performance and convenience during development.  I obviously do not want to commit these changes when I commit others.  I would like to automatically omit them from my outgoing change set in the Eclipse Team Synchronizing view, but not miss out on committed changes from others.  Right now, I have to keep remembering to manually remove them before committing my other changes.  Changing the .cvsignore file or Ignored Resources pattern set will ignore both incoming and outgoing changes.  Is a "one-way" cvsignore possible?  I know I would have to remember to change it if I ever wanted to commit a change to one of these files.  Thanks for any input!

Comment: Looking for the same thing....